# Uniform Convergence of Taylor Remainder

Tags: limits, derivatives, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence

For $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, let $f(x)=(x+1) e^{x}$. After finding the $k$ th Taylor polynomial for $f$ at $x_{0}=0$ and the corresponding Lagrange form of the remainder $R_{k}(0 ; x)$,

prove that $$\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} R_{k}(0 ; x)=0$$ (uniformly) on $\mathbb{R}$.

I have found the $k$ th derivative as $(x+k+1)e^x$, and $R_{k}(0 ; x)= \frac{(c+k+2)x^{k+2}}{(k+1)!} e^c$ for some $c$ lying strictly between $0$ and $x$. However, since the domain is considered as $\mathbb{R}$, I don't know how to proceed for proving the uniform convergence of the remainder using the limit. Are there any alternative approaches for it, such as dividing the domain into finite subintervals or maybe considering $x$ as the fixed value?

Comment: You calculated right the $k$-th derivative, but that's not the remainder.

Comment: Could you please suggest what could be done for the remainder? I already edited it (had a small typo there) and would be welcomed to know how the uniform convergence could be derived?

Comment: It should be $\frac{(c+k+2)x^{k+\color{red}{1}}}{(k+1)!} e^c$, but that's not really important. Now, to answer your question: the convergence is NOT uniform. What you are trying to prove is false.